# What historian databases are available currently?

Tags: historian, wonderware

I have a question related to the historian databases. Here is our requirement.
We need a historian database that is capable of collecting data from equipment at the rate of 1000 updates / sec on an average. And there will be one equipment for each historian database. Given this requirement, which is the best suited historian database for my requirement? 
I had looked at many options including OSISoft's PI System, Wonderware historian, Canary logger from canary labs, GE proficy, Iconic's hyperhistorian and so on.
This link helped me: 
[Historian Comparison](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Historian-Comparison-39667.S.50536264)

But the biggest problem I have is that these historians are highly scalable databases which means it can collect the whole factory data. So, using this for one equipment with say 500 datapoints might be overkill and expensive.

I am wondering if you guys can help me with the list of historian databases that can fit my need.

Comment: Guys, just wanted to update you guys on this one. Out of all these canary logger seems to be best fit as it can cater for both desktop and server environments.

Answer (score 0):

Go for GE Proficy Historian version 5.5. This version is capable to create number of datastores depending upon historian license. But definately it is advanced version and only version with which you can create many archives. You have to create datastore in historian, You can create one archive per datastore.
You can segregate tags to send data to perticular archive